# Highlighting sections of an image on mouseover in a way that is responsive to browser size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I always appreciate the help given here. I am working on trying to figure out how to make div boxes highlight a specific area of an image using html, css, and jquery. I have been doing some reading on image maps and they seem rather complex and not necessarily the best option anyway. So I started making this example that I will include on a jsfiddle.net. The example is the ability to mouseover a tooth and select it. Here's my question, is this the best way of solving this problem? Most important is that in the end it is responsive to window size change and across multiple browsers. I am worried that the divs won't always match up and be the correct size. It would be nice if I could make it look better, but I am not sure how. Any help or pointers or general thoughts are appreciated in making this more functional. I'm still pretty new at this. Thanks.

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/creedjm/3gpK6/50/

Stack would like me to submit a snippet of code before it can be accepted. Here is the current html, css, and jquery.

HTML:

```
<div class="mouth" id="mouthAndDivs">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1318823/virtudent/images/mouth.jpg" id="theMouth"/>
    <div class="tooth" id="tooth1"></div>
    <div class="tooth" id="tooth2"></div>
    <div class="tooth" id="tooth3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mouthAndDivs {
    position:absolute;
}

.tooth {
    position: relative;
    width:40px;
    height:27px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

}

#tooth1 {
    left: 260px;
    top: 270px;
    width:42px;
}

#tooth2 {
    left:266px;
    top:210px;
    width: 45px;
}

#tooth3{
    left:275px;
    top:148px;
    width:42px;
}

#theMouth {
    position:absolute;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".tooth").mouseenter( function() {
    $( this ).css( "border", "2px solid rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)" );
});

$(".tooth").mouseleave( function() {
    $( this ).css( "border", "2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)" );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to worry about responsiveness, any absolutely positioned element is positioned according to it's closest positioned (absolute, relative, or fixed) parent.

That means that you only need to change this:

```
#mouthAndDivs {
    position: relative;
}
```